# How to access the a table ABC_XXX constantly in Teradata where XXX changes periodically?

Tags: database, teradata, synonym

I have a table in Teradata ABC_XXX where **XXX** will change monthly basis.
For Ex: ABC_1902, ABC_1812, ABC_1904 etc...

I need to access this table in my application without modifying the code every month.

Is that any way to do in Teradata or any alternate solution.??

Please help

Comment: Create the table name dynamically in your application based on the current month or setup a process which does a similar `replace view ABC as select  * from ABC_1909;`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using DBC.TABLES in subquery like below:

```
  with tbl as  (select  'select * from ' ||  databasename||'.'||tablename as tb from 
  dbc.tables where tablename like 'ABC_%')
  select * from tbl;
```

If you can get the final query executed in your application, you will be able to query the required table without editing the query.

The above solution is with expectation that the previous month's table gets dropped whenever a new month's table is created.

However, if previous table is not being dropped, then you can try the below approach:

```
select 'select * from db.ABC_' ||to_char(current_date,'YYMM')
```

Output will be

```
select * from db.ABC_1902
```

execute the output in your application, you will be able to query dynamic table.